# Slightly modify style in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Edit: I tried making a MWE, I hope it is correct this way. If not, please let me know!

.tex document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    bibstyle=authortitle,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=true, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{% 
urlseen = {Stand:}, 
}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{% 
  \iffieldundef{shorthand} 
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}} 
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}% 
        \setunit{\addspace}} 
       {\printnames{labelname}% 
        \setunit{\addspace}% 
        \ifnamesequal{labelname}{editor} 
          {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}} 
          {}% 
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}% 
     \ifentrytype{online} 
     {\setunit{\addcomma\space}% 
        \usebibmacro{urldate}
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\setunit{\addcomma\space}% 
        \usebibmacro{url}
        } 
       {}} }
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}   

\addbibresource{MWE.bib} 

\begin{document}

This is cited from a book \footcite[Vgl.][32\psq]{fritzsch}

This is cited from a website \footcite[Vlg.][]{paulip}

\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

.bib document:

```
@Online{paulip,
  title   = {Pauli-Prinzip},
  url     = {http://www.chemie.de/lexikon/Pauli-Prinzip.html},
  urldate = {2018-08-12},
}

@Book{fritzsch,
  author    = {Harald Fritzsch},
  title     = {Elementarteilchen - Bausteine der Materie},
  year      = {2004},
  publisher = {Verlag C.H. Beck},
  location  = {München},
}
```

I'm using biblatex and have some issues with citing the way I am required to.

There are three things I need to change, but I am totally lost on how I can do it.

1. The "renewbibmacro" snippet of code (which I found online when I wanted to display the url and the date when the url was seen in footcites too when the author is unknown) also changed that the year suddenly isn't shown on book entries anymore, which was not intended. A book footcite should look like this:

[image]

2. I would like the "Stand: urldate" to be displayed after the url and if possible in square brackets [], not round ones ()
3. What do I need to do so that the last and first name are not separated by a comma in the bibliography and there is a comma instead of a period after the name? Meaning instead of

   "Fritzsch, Harald. Elementarteilchen - Bausteine der Materie. München: Verlag 
   C.H. Beck, 2004."

   it is

   "Fritzsch Harald, Elementarteilchen - Bausteine der Materie. München: Verlag 
   C.H. Beck, 2004."

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a *complete* (yet minimal) code reproducing the problem.

Comment: It is much easier to answer questions like this if the code is not posted in several snippets, but as one fully compilable document (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 or MWEB https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). It is also generally strongly preferred to ask only one question per question and not several (related, no doubt) questions in one. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I tried making a (hopefully correct) MWE and will remember to post separate questions for every single problem next time.

Comment: Did you find the snippet for the URL in https://golatex.de/mit-footcite-auch-url-angeben-styleauthoryear-t16461.html or somewhere else? Do you also want to retain the feature of that code to write "editor"/"Herausgeber" after the name also in citations?

Comment: I believe it was that website, but to be honest I'm not 100% sure. And I don't want  "editor"/"Herausgeber" written after the name, I didn't even realise the code had that feature.

Comment: Can you clarify point 3, please? I don't quite understand what you are going for. Can you show the output you expect to see in the example.

Comment: I tried to clarify it a bit; the change is only subtle, but I hope that you can see what I mean now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try the following.

The comma between family and given name is controlled with `\revsdnamepunct`, the comma between label/sort name and title with `nametitledelim`.

I have modernised the `cite` bibmacro redefinition based on the current definition in `authoryear.cbx`. The only difference to the original is the added block

```
     \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnameundef{labelname}} and test {\ifentrytype{online}}}
       {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
       {}
```

that prints URL and access date for `@online` entries without (author/label) name.

The `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}` bit takes care of the square brackets. Compare the new definition to the original in [`biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L533).

The `\DeclareLabeldate`s make sure that the `urldate` is not used to populate the label date used for citations and suppresses the 'n.d.'/nodate string for `@online` entries.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=authoryear,
    bibstyle=authortitle,
    sorting=nyt,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
     \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnameundef{labelname}} and test {\ifentrytype{online}}}
       {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
       {}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  urlseen = {Stand},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \literal{nodate}
}

\DeclareLabeldate[online]{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{paulip,
  title   = {Pauli-Prinzip},
  url     = {http://www.chemie.de/lexikon/Pauli-Prinzip.html},
  urldate = {2018-08-12},
}
@book{fritzsch,
  author    = {Harald Fritzsch},
  title     = {Elementarteilchen},
  subtitle  = {Bausteine der Materie},
  year      = {2004},
  publisher = {Verlag C.H. Beck},
  location  = {München},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is cited from a book \footcite[Vgl.][32\psq]{fritzsch}

This is cited from a website \footcite[Vlg.][]{paulip}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Vgl. Fritzsch, 2004, S. 32 f.//Vlg. Pauli-Prinzip, url: http : / / www . chemie . de / lexikon / Pauli - Prinzip . html [Stand: 12.08.2018].]

Comment: This is exactly how it is supposed to look; thank you so much for helping a LaTeX beginner out, I honestly appreciate it. ^^